# When is One Punch Man season 2 airing?

Tags: one-punch-man

I heard that season 2 of *One Punch Man* will be aired only after the Toonami broadcast of season 1 is over. Does anyone know when the second season will be broadcast, or rather, when the Toonami dub will end?

Comment: I believe December '16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The English dub. airing of season 1 on Toonami has ended already. And yes, it is true that season 2 will air after the season 1 airing. Although they haven't told us when exactly, it is expected to be airing in early 2017, but then again it could air in the Spring or even the Summer of next year.

Sources:

- [One Punch Man 2 Latest Updates, News, Spoilers, And Release Dates](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/40131/20161012/one-punch-man-2-latest-updates-news-spoilers-release-date.htm)

Comment: It's not even yet released on April 2018, and the speculation doesn't really help answering the question at all...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Netflix release One Punch Man season 2 should be released in August 2018. This is according to:http://otlsm.com/when-will-one-punch-man-season-2-be-on-netflix-netflix-release-date/

> One of our reliable sources has informed us that One Punch Man season
>   2 should be released on television by the end of August 2018.

But, sometimes release dates get pushed back.

Comment: "*One of our reliable sources has informed us that One Punch Man season 2 should be released on television by the end of August 2017*" turns out it's wrong since it's not even yet released on April 2018.